# Curl strips CRLF in the xml-file

Tags: xml, curl

I use curl to call a webservice in order to receive a xml-file containing information.

But when I look into to the received xml-file la3.xml all crls's are stripped and the information is
on one line. The webservice is loacated on a Microsoft IIS server and I am on a UNIX box.

How can I preserve the crlf?

/Amanseb

Comment: Use an xml library to parse the received XML and then serialize it again specifying that you would like to have line breaks.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that it's curl stripping them and not simply that the service is sending the data like that? Try something like wireshark to see the actual data that's coming over the network.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the -d or --data options, they're equivalent to specifying --data-ascii, and will result in stripping the carriage return / newline characters.  To preserve these use --data-binary instead.

Excerpt from `curl`'s manual:

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file
> name  to  read  the data  from, or - if you want curl to read the data
> from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a
> file named from a file like that,  carriage  returns and newlines will
> be stripped out. If you don't want the @ character to have a special
> interpretation use --data-raw instead.